# How to use Resource object as a children of a Panel using xaml?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Suppose I has an Image object in my Resource Dictionary like this:

```
<Image x:Key="Theme_Icon_Microphone" Source="Images/icon_microphone.png"/>
```

I want to use this object in DockPanel

```
<DockPanel>
  <!-- My Image object -->
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an `Image` as a static resource because you will only be able to use it once.  Instead put a `BitmapImage` in resources and reference that from your `Image`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" x:Key="image"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource image}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```